# How do I convert a DateTime variable to return date in the 'mm/dd/yy' format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

```
private DateTime OrderDate;
OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime("05/20/15")
```

How do I assign the above OrderDate variable a value of 05/20/15.

I tried using Convert.ToDateTime, but it seems to work for yyyy format but not yy.

Comment: All you've shown is a field. That's just a date and time - it doesn't have a format. We have no idea how you're converting that to or from a string...

Comment: Each `DateTime` object has different attributes just like `Year`, `Month` and `Day`... You can easily initialize them by valid integer values you would like...

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I have modified my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign it, you would use `OrderDate = new DateTime(2015, 5, 20);`

When displaying the value the .Net Framework will use the local culture or your machine.

If you want to use a different display format, (without changing the culture) you can use `String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", OrderDate)`

Comment: Thanks. I need the OrderDate in mm/dd/yy format. So, this DateTime variable(not string) should return me a date of 05/20/15.

Comment: What you're actually asking for ... is that the DateTime *value* should be **decoded** into a printable string that conforms to a particular, specified, *format.*  You do that by asking for the value to be decoded, and supplying the format-string that you want to use.  Remember that "the 'value of'" a DateTime, internally speaking, is "just a floating-point number."  But its value is *opaque.* You don't care what it actually is.  You can **encode** a string (or a vector of numbers) to produce it, then **manipulate** it (using provided *methods*!), then finally **decode** it for printing.

Comment: @Rob, I'm pretty sure (open to correction here) that the date format you see when you inspect the variable is driven by the culture of your machine.  The internal implementation of `DateTime` is culture agnostic - it stores a date in its own way, the format/culture etc. only matters when you wish to display it and (as numerous posters have already pointed out) the default format is machine culture dependent but (again, as pointed out by many) there are techniques and classes allowing you to control this.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to create a new date time object and assign it to the property.

```
OrderDate = new DateTime(2015, 5, 20);
```

Comment: I think he is talking about a 2 digit year that he has in his format. e.g. 15 instead of 2015

Comment: He is asking how his date time property can be assigned this value. He needs to change his question for what you are suggesting.

Comment: Thanks. I need the OrderDate in mm/dd/yy format. So, the variable should return me a date of 05/20/15.

Comment: @Rob: The variable is just a `DateTime`. It doesn't have a format. You can format it using `ToString` and providing whatever format you want. It's really important that you understand the difference between what the `DateTime` stores, and how it can be represented in a string...

Answer (score 0):

Lots of info about converting/formatting dates you can find here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I guess in particular you need this example:

MSDN snippet:

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] dateValues = { "30-12-2011", "12-30-2011", 
                              "30-12-11", "12-30-11" };
      string pattern = "MM-dd-yy";
      DateTime parsedDate;

      foreach (var dateValue in dateValues) {
         if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null, 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1:d}.", 
                              dateValue, parsedDate);
         else
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date and time.", 
                              dateValue);
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//    Unable to convert '30-12-2011' to a date and time. 
//    Unable to convert '12-30-2011' to a date and time. 
//    Unable to convert '30-12-11' to a date and time. 
//    Converted '12-30-11' to 12/30/2011.
```

Comment: I imagine that Jon Skeet might disagree that that's everything one needs to know :)  But it should suffice for the original question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll update my text to "Lots of info about".. to prevent further discussion about this type of textual details :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Unless you change the date string  to the correct format, **it cannot guess which millennium you are reffering.**

or you can take each part of the date sepretly and pass it in the constructor:

```
OrderDate = new DateTime(2015, 5, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact to achieve this

```
DateTime OrderDate = DateTime.ParseExact("05/20/15", "MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime time;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("05/20/15", "MM/dd/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out time))
{
   do something ...
}
```